# Is there any way to clear table view content widhout using reloadData

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Is there any way to clear table view content without using [tableView reloadData];

Comment: Do you mean empty the tableview?

Comment: It'd be easier to help you if you explain why you'd need to avoid `reloadData`.

Comment: @user1683062 it is possible by looping through the subviews of tableView to get the tableViewCell and then set empty string to 'cell.textLabel.text'

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, if you do not clear your TableView's datasource, when a user scrolls the table it will populate you the table with new/reused cells with the appropriate content. You could use the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` TableView method but again, once the cells are removed it will attempt to populate the table with whatever is left in the datasource. So make sure you clear that out first.